# TEST CONDITION vs. TEST SCENARIO (same or different?)

Tags: testing

I have been searching for the difference between TEST CONDITION vs TEST SCENARIO, it seems that they are the same. Can anyone explain to me the difference? And can you please give me specific examples of each? I just want to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Some context in which you came across these terms would be useful. In the end it means whatever the author wants it to mean; just by themselves these words are just words.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is quite old, but I feel people get too hung up on terminology. There are far too many words to describe 'things' in testing. The ISTQB define a Test Condition as:

'An aspect of the test basis that is relevant in order to achieve specific test objectives.' - http://glossary.istqb.org/search/test%20condition

and the Test Basis is:

'The body of knowledge used as the basis for test analysis and design.' - http://glossary.istqb.org/search/test%20basis

Which in English is: Requirements (Test Basis) inform what you can Test (Test Condition) and from this, you make scenarios/cases.

In the picture below, the requirements define what the 'Functionality' circle is. Such as 'The user must be able to add a note', 'The user must be able to delete a note' etc.

Then from this, there is a main Test Condition of 'Create Note' and further Test Conditions of Add, Edit, Save, Delete and Close then from these conditions you would write test cases that examine this functionality.

[image: Functional GUI Test]

Comment: Please write here the solution instead of including a link (or image) that could be broken in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> ### Test Scenarios
>
> - Test scenarios are possible ways to test an application. Example: For testing you have so many ways like positive testing, negative
>     testing, BVA etc.
> - Test scenarios can be a single or a group of test cases.
> - It is important when time is less and most team members understand the details from one line scenarios.
> - Good test coverage can be achieved by dividing an application in test scenarios which reduces the complexity.
> - Test scenarios are rather vague and covers wide range of possibilities.
>
> ### Test Conditions
>
> - Test conditions are the constraints that you should follow to test an application. Example: When User Name and Password are valid then
>     application will move forward.
> - Test conditions can be a piece of functionality or anything you want to verify. In simple terms the goal of a test case.
> - It is an item or event of a system that could be verified by one or more test cases. Eg; transaction, function, structural element etc.
> - Good test conditions ensure a system is bug free
> - Test conditions are very specific

I took this from: http://www.guru99.com/test-scenario-vs-test-condition.html

There is a lot of information available online, just googling "test condition" gave me a load of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one line pointer that testers create as an initial, transitional step into the test design phase. This is mostly a one line definition of “What” we are going to test with respect to a certain feature. Usually, test scenarios are an input for the creation of test cases. In agile projects, Test scenarios are the only test design outputs and no test cases are written following these. A test scenario might result in multiple tests.

Examples test scenarios:

1. Validate if a new country can be added by the Admin
2. Validate if an existing country can be deleted by the admin
3. Validate if an existing country can be updated

Test conditions on the other hand are more specific. It can be roughly defined as the aim/goal of a certain test.

Example test condition:
In the above example, if we were to test the scenario 1, we can test the following conditions:
1. Enter the country name as “India”(valid )and check for the addition of the country
2. Enter a blank and check if the country gets added.
In each case, the specific data is described and the goal of the test is much more precise.

Comment: I don't think that you have described a Test Condition. A test condition informs the scenario/cases and not the other way around.

The ISTQB say in the syllabus - https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/10-advanced-level-syllabus-2012/54-advanced-level-syllabus-2012-test-manager.html

'For example, you might have a single general test condition, “Test checkout,” for an e-commerce
application. However, in a detailed test condition document, this might be split into multiple test
conditions.'

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to visit the [istqb glossary](https://glossary.istqb.org/en/search/)
which is the official glossary for the ISTQB organization, if you do now know what ISTQB is, then we have a problem, going back to your question,
test scenario is synonym for test procedure specification
test procedure specification: Documentation specifying one or more test procedures.
Test Condition: A testable aspect of a component or system identified as a basis for testing.
Synonyms: test requirement , test situation

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar topic: Test conditions represent an item or event of a component or system that could be verified by one or more test cases.
You can check out at https://youtu.be/PPgHhAsk-EA If you are interested in Test Conditions

Answer (score 0):

In simple/short answer (Same) , but if you need a details , get it from: https://glossary.istqb.org/en/search/